# MySQL: Updating parent record when child is updated (Node with Sequelize)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following tables:

`Groups`
`Members`

`Groups` -> `Members`.   `Groups` has to-Many relationship with `Members`.

What's the best practice to update the `Groups` `updatedAt` column when one of the `Members` record is updated. I'm Using Sequlize ORM.

Currently, I am updating the `Members` record, then fetching the `Groups` record that belongs to that `Members` table, and updating the `updatedAt` column with the current date.  I have a feeling there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize doesn't provide native definitions for "triggers" because their implementations vary so much by target database. However, there are two methods you could use to do this:

1. If you don't mind database-specific code, you could easily use raw SQL queries (even via Sequelize) to issue an ALTER TABLE command to do this triggered update.
2. You could use Sequelize Hooks (e.g. `afterUpdate`) to do this in Sequelize itself, cross-platform. See the [Hooks Documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/) for more information.

Personally I prefer Hooks, but there is one caveat with them: they work only as long as you're using Sequelize for all your update work. They don't get translated into database triggers, so if you update your database manually (e.g. with an admin tool) the update won't be performed.